# Is there a way to add a folder to existing 7za archive?

Tags: 7zip, zip

I have tried adding a new folder to an existing 7za archive using the following command from command prompt:

```
7za.exe a repo.zip \res\pub\newfolder newfolder
```

The above command added a folder to root of repo.zip. My intention was to add the new folder to location: \res\pub\folder inside repo.zip

Can anyone suggest or give me a correct command to add folder to a specific path of an archive?

Thanks,
Pradeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a source location folder which you use for an update of your destination archive.

e.g.

7za.exe a "x:\destination_archive.7z" -up1q0r2x1y2z1w2 "c:\source_folder\*" -t7z -ms=off -mx1

I use this line of code every day to update a 7-zip archive. You need to adjust the '-u' parameter to your needs.