# An appendable compressed archive

Tags: unix, compression, append, archive

I have a requirement to maintain a compressed archive of log files.  The log filenames are unique and the archive, once expanded, is simply one directory containing all the log files.

The current solution isn't scaling well, since it involves a gzipped tar file.  Every time a log file is added, they first decompress the entire archive, add the file, and re-gzip.

Is there a Unix archive tool that can add to a compressed archive without completely expanding and re-compressing?  Or can gzip perform this, given the right combination of arguments?

Answer (score 5):

I'm using `zip -Zb` for that (appending text logs incrementally to compressed archive):

- fast append (index is at the end of archive, efficient to update)
- `-Zb` uses *bzip2* compression method instead of *deflate*. In 2018 this seems safe to use (you'll need a reasonably modern `unzip` -- note some tools do assume *deflate* when they see a zip file, so YMMV)
- `7z` was a good candidate: compression ratio is vastly better than zip when you compress all files in the same operation. But when you append files one by one to the archive (incremental appending), compression ratio is only marginally better than standard zip, and similar to `zip -Zb`. So for now I'm sticking with `zip -Zb`.

To clarify what happens and why having the index at the end is useful for "appendable" archive format, with entries compressed individually:

```
Before:
############## ########### ################# #
[foo1.png    ] [foo2.png ] [foo3.png       ] ^
                                             |
                                         index

After:
############## ########### ################# ########### #
[foo1.png    ] [foo2.png ] [foo3.png       ] [foo4.png ] ^
                                                         |
                                                 new index
```

So this is not `fopen` in `append` mode, but presumably `fopen` in `write` mode, then `fseek`, then `write` (that's my mental model of it, someone let me know if this is wrong). I'm not 100% certain that it would be so simple in reality, it might depend on OS and file system (e.g. a file system with snapshots might have a very different opinion about how to deal with small writes at the end of a file… huge "YMMV" here ‍♂️)

Comment: Could you explain how this works? How can you append to a zip file then?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. Zip file contains N compressed entries + 1 index at the very end. When you add a new entry to it, I guess the zip utility will read the index in memory (small enough), write the new entry over the place where the index was (so, not touching previous entries, but likely extending the length of the file), then write a new updated index at the end.

Comment: Ah, my misunderstanding came from an archive containing a single file, and updating that file in it. My bad. It's very clear now.

Answer (score 3):

It's rather easy to have an appendable archive of compressed files (not same as appendable compressed archive, though).

`tar` has an option to append files to the end of an archive (Assuming that you have GNU tar)

```
 -r, --append
       append files to the end of an archive
```

You can `gzip` the log files *before* adding to the archive and can continue to update (append) the archive with newer files.

```
$ ls -l
foo-20130101.log
foo-20130102.log
foo-20130103.log
$ gzip foo*
$ ls -l
foo-20130101.log.gz
foo-20130102.log.gz
foo-20130103.log.gz
$ tar cvf backup.tar foo*gz
```

Now you have another log file to add to the archive:

```
$ ls -l
foo-20130104.log
$ gzip foo-20130104.log
$ tar rvf backup.tar foo-20130104.log
$ tar tf backup.tar
foo-20130101.log.gz
foo-20130102.log.gz
foo-20130103.log.gz
foo-20130104.log.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use `tar`, I suggest 7-Zip. It has an 'add' command, which I believe does what you want.

See related SO question: [Is there a way to add a folder to existing 7za archive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025334/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-folder-to-existing-7za-archive)

Also, the 7-Zip documentation: https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/add.htm